# data list API not called when making API call in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, fetch-api

I want to call API data in the form of a list based on ID, but what happens is that the data is not called and is not consoled, does not give a success 200 response and the widget only displays a circularprogresindicator, where is the error, thanks in advance.

I've tried to modify the previous code but it's still not resolved, and I'm a little confused here.

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  // DetailPage({Key? key, required Posts posts}) : super(key: key);

  final Datum posts;
  DetailPage({Key? key, required this.posts}) : super(key: key);

  Future<List<Mk>> getDetail(String id) async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/kurikulum/detail/$id',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Data detailKurikulum = Data.fromJson(result['data']);
      List<Mk>? l = detailKurikulum.mk;
      return l!;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }

  Future<List<Mk>>? futureMk;

  void initState(String id) {
    futureMk = DetailKurikulumProvider.getDetail(id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: CustomAppbar(
          title: 'Detail Kurikulum',
        ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              headerDetail(),
              bodyDetail(),
              Text(
                'id: ${posts.name}',
              ),
              Text('Title: ${posts.prodi}'),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              const Text('Body: '),
              Text(posts.id.toString())
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  Widget bodyDetail() {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Mk>>(
      future: futureMk,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          // print('This is .... ${snapshot.data}');
          return Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 3),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(8),
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                          blurRadius: 9,
                          offset: const Offset(
                            1,
                            2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      child: ExpansionTile(
                        textColor: Colors.black,
                        iconColor: primaryColor,
                        collapsedIconColor: primaryColor,
                        title: Text(snapshot.data![index].matakuliah.toString(),
                            style: boldTile),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'Bobot Mata Kuliah (SKS)',
                            style: bold6,
                          ),
                          Table(
                            border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.grey),
                            children: [
                              TableRow(children: [
                                Column(children: [Text('Wajib', style: bold6)]),
                                Column(
                                    children: [Text('Pilihan', style: bold6)]),
                                Column(children: [
                                  Text('Sertifikat', style: bold6)
                                ]),
                              ]),
                              TableRow(children: [
                                Column(children: [
                                  Text(
                                      snapshot.data![index].jumlahSksWajib
                                          .toString(),
                                      style: regular6,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                ]),
                                Column(children: [
                                  Text(
                                      snapshot.data![index].jumlahSksPilihan
                                          .toString(),
                                      style: regular6,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                ]),
                                Column(children: [
                                  Text(
                                      snapshot.data![index].jumlahSksSertifikat
                                          .toString(),
                                      style: regular6,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                ]),
                              ]),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: primaryColor),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: with out knowing exception it is hard to tell what is stopping it. Breakpoint on these two conditions check what status code it is getting after that only you'll get to know actual error.

if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      final result = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Data detailKurikulum = Data.fromJson(result['data']);
      List<Mk>? l = detailKurikulum.mk;
      return l!;
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }

Comment: how do i check it? i am a little confused

Comment: which IDE are you using? Android studio or VS code

Comment: i'm use vs code

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=debug+flutter+app+in+vscode

have a go at any of these videos because it is very important for you to learn debugging

Comment: In the meanwhile add print(response.statusCode) in else block 

else {
//here
   print(response.statusCode)
      throw Exception();
    }